# Lowpass filter (LPF) for ADC with cutoff frequency much lower than fs/2?

Tags: adc, signal-processing

I was reading the datasheet from the ADS868x ADCs and it seems that in its internal circuit schematic it uses a 2nd Order LPF before the ADC driver, as the picture shows.
[image: Simplified ADC circuit]

According to the datasheet, the LPF -3 dB cutoff frequency is at 15 kHz. [image: LPF Magnitude and Phase response] Considering that the maximum sample rate for the ADC is 1 MSPS, fs/2 would be 500 kHz. Why would they do that? Doesn't this attenuate a lot of the higher frequency components of the original data? If they wanted to prevent aliasing, shouldn't they use a cutoff frequency closer to fs/2?

[Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8681.pdf?ts=1635274552285)

Comment: Pretty common on audio ADCs/DACs to set the sampling rate 256 times or more higher than the low pass cut off. Some applications really cannot tolerate any aliasing or imaging while requiring a very flat pass band.

Comment: Pls include citation links to datasheet

Comment: The clue is "2nd order", or 40dB/decade rolloff. That means, if you need better than 40dB attenuation of aliasing products, the cutoff frequency must be at least a decade below Fs/2. Or, a higher order filter.

Comment: The breakpoint actually looks like < 12kHz at -3dB but 2 decades up at 1MHz *40 dB/dec = -66 dB attenuation at 500 kHz and -78 dB ~ 1MHz with - 12dB / octave means if input SNR >16:1 ~ >= 24 dB before filtering ignoring noise < breakpoint it will  80 dB better after filtering and decimation. So always consider  Dynamic range  for SNR input and output

Comment: The Nyquist theorem only assumes an SNR =0 dB . it can neither accurate sample amplitude or phase for any signal at fs/2 except with averaging -20 log (sqrt(N)) samples but with 16 bits you need a SNR of 2^16 = 96 dB to see quantization noise limiting your dynamic range

Answer (score 2):

So, it's a \$2^{nd}\$-order filter, and the **3dB cutoff** frequency is at \$15\mathrm{kHz}\$.

It's a 16-bit ADC.  The gain of the filter at 1MHz is about $$A_{f_s} = \left ( \mathrm {\frac{15kHz}{1MHz}} \right )^2 = 0.000225 \simeq 2^{-12}$$.

So at their "typical" filter cutoff, a signal at 1MHz is only attenuated by a factor of 12 bits -- and it's a 16-bit ADC, *and* that 1MHz signal will alias down to DC.  Since you're presumably most interested in DC signals, that means that a 1MHz signal with magnitude similar to the DC signals you're interested in will reduce your accuracy from the ADC's 16 bits down to 12 bits.

That's why the cutoff is so "low" -- and depending on your application, it may be way too high.

Comment: You may be assuming a full scale noise signal . I think TI assumed that for 1 Msps that Nyquist noise at Fs/2 would be 4 bits lower than full scale. or an SNR of at least 16 using 1MHz noise.  This is why OSR the oversampling ratio only needs a 2nd order filter instead of a brick wall with GD distortion.

Comment: Well, I'm _stating_ a full scale noise signal.  I'm also pointing out that the filter you need depends on the application.  The data sheet implies that the filter cutoff is variable, but I didn't find out how before I decided I'd put enough effort into datasheet-reading.

Comment: regardless of any datasheet, I'm just saying they must have made assumptions on input SNR at 1MHz before choosing 15 kHz with 16bits and 1Msps. I didn't read it either.  Although the loglog graph looks more like 12 kHz

Comment: Oh, agreed.  Either they just spitballed a bandwidth, or they had one **big** customer that wanted 15kHz, or they had some accumulated knowledge of how people were using these in the field.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the slope of a 2nd order is quite soft and not a brick-wall filter that removes everything beyond the cut-off.

If the sampling rate Fs is 1 Msps, and you set the cutoff to Fs/2 which is 500 kHz, the incoming signal is only attenuated by 3dB at 500 kHz cut-off, and since the second order filter has a slope of 12 dB per octave, it will only have about 12dB of attenuation at 1 MHz.

This basically means that any signal at 1 MHz that appears on the ADC input is only attenuated to 25% of the original amplitude and will get folded back to DC.

So in general, if you want to sample at 1 Msps, you better have all unwanted signals attenuated to silence at 500 KHz, which means the cut-off frequency must be far below that for the passband amplitude to attenuate to levels far below -96dB of the 16-bit DAC when frequency reaches 500 kHz, as the slope of attenuation is only 40dB per decade or 12dB per octave.

Answer (score 1):

The AD8681 whose datasheet you linked to is part of a [larger family of ADCs.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads8688)

The last digit of the part number tells you how many input channels the IC has.  The AD8681 has one input channel.  The AD8684 has four input channels.  The AD8688 has eight channels.

No matter how many input channels there are, however, they all have only a single ADC onboard.

The AD8688 has to spread the 1MSPS across eight channels.  That makes the 15kHz bandwidth limit for each channel much more reasonable.

You have at most 125kSPS for each of the eight channels.  A cutoff of 15kHz means an attenuation of about 30 dB at 60kHz - adequate for antialiasing if your signal doesn't have a lot of high frequency content.

The smaller versions are made by simplifying the AD8688.  They all share the same basic circuitry, though, and retain the filters in all versions.

---

For all I know, the actual chip in all versions may be the same, with only the number of pins connected to the outside different and maybe a one time settable option that they use to tell the chip to only handle the channels it has connected.